# How to Add a check Constraint to Doctrine Annotation in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine

Suppose I have a field `gender` in my `Person` entity which can take any of following values

- MALE
- FEMALE
- OTHERS

How can I provide this check using doctrine ORM annotation and then create a corresponding radio button in form using `php app/console generate:doctrine:crud`?

Can I do that directly? Or do I have to rely on manual approach?

Comment: The question is how to DO it generally or how to do it EXACTLY WITH `php app/console generate:doctrine:crud ` command?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the valid choices using a [Choice constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html) as an ORM annotation with your entity property. The Symfony book even uses gender as the example.

In your case the array would be **{"MALE", "FEMALE", "OTHER"}**, and you may not want that validation error message.

As this validation is in the annotation format you will need to enable annotation validation in your Symfony app configuration (config.yml), I believe this is still disabled by default.